# Command line DateAthost client

Tags: java, tcp, network-programming

Write a client application which sets machine time to a given host after that it prints new value
of date. The application uses a standard date at host service which available in TCP port 37.
The arguments are hostname and port number. The default value of port number is 37. If the
program is ran without arguments it communicates with localhost. Program uses standard
output to print information.
Important note:
dateAtHost service gives a signed 32 bit integer with number of seconds since 1st January,
1990.
DateAtHost server
Write a server application which listens on given TCP port and it sends date in 32 bit integer
format to clients like standard date at host service. The program argument is the port number.
The default value of port number is 37. Program uses standard output to print information.

```
DateAthostclient.java

package DateAthostclient;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DateAthostclient {
   static final int defaultPort = 37;
   static final long offset = 2208988800L;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int portNumber;
    Socket clientSocket;
    DataInputStream timeStream;
    String hostName;
    switch(args.length) {
    case 1: hostName = args[0];
    portNumber = defaultPort;//dateAtHost Port;
    break;
    case 2: hostName = args[0];
    portNumber = new Integer(args[1]).intValue();
    break;
    default:
    hostName = "localhost";
    portNumber = defaultPort;//dateAtHost Port;
   }

   try {
   clientSocket = new Socket(hostName,portNumber);
   timeStream = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
   int dateAtHost = timeStream.readInt() + (int)(1L<<32);
   new Date().setTime((dateAtHost-offset)*1000);
   System.out.println("It is " + new Date().toString() + " at " +hostName);
   timeStream.close();
    clientSocket.close();
   }
   catch (UnknownHostException {
   System.err.println(" Unknown host error");
   }
   catch (ConnectException e) {
   System.out.println(" Service unavailable on port "+portNumber+"of host       "+hostName);
   }
  catch (IOException e) {
  System.err.println(" Communication error occured\r\n "+e);
  }
  }

 }


dayAtHostserver.java
package dayAtHostserver;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
 public class dayAtHostserver {
 public final static int daytimePort = 13;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    ServerSocket theServerSocket;
    Socket theConnectionSocket;
    PrintWriter out;
    try {
    theServerSocket = new ServerSocket(daytimePort);
    System.out.println("Timeserver ready at port "+daytimePort);
    try {
    while (true) {
    theConnectionSocket = theServerSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Request arrived!");
    out = new PrintWriter(theConnectionSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
    out.println(new Date());
    theConnectionSocket.close();
    }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
    theServerSocket.close();
    System.err.println(e);
     }
     }
    catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println(e);

    }
    }
    }
```

> > i have two problem 
> >     1) i need to understand what is (1L<32) and why he use it here ???
> >     2) when i run server and client date not receive in client

Comment: 1) `1L << 32` is a bit-shifted 1, or `4294967296`.

Comment: 1L << 32 will left shift the bit that makes number 1 (taken as a long) for 32 positions to the left which results in 2^32

Comment: int dateAtHost = timeStream.readInt() + (int)(1L<<32);
   new Date().setTime((dateAtHost-offset)*1000);
why this two line??